# Is there an equivalent of a preprocessor instruction in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In the Dockerfile, is there a way to detect whether the Docker engine is running Linux or Windows containers and then switch instruction types in the file e.g. execute a dir command instead of find?

Is the better approach to create a batch/shell that wraps the Dockerfile and perform switch that way?  More of creating a 1 file to rule them all without having to determine how the engine is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general when I've done this sort of thing I've found it easiest to write a Dockerfile that does exactly one thing, and to write multiple Dockerfiles if you need substantially different behavior.  In the case you describe, I'd expect Windows vs. Linux container setup to be so different (*every* command will be different) that I'd just write a separate Dockerfile.

If an image will be very lightly parameterized – you might want to run essentially the same thing on different JVMs, say, but the install process is the same no matter which one – ARGs can address this.  You can use shell logic within an individual RUN command to make decisions based on an ARG value.

If you do need more than this, then Docker doesn't have a built-in preprocessor, but Dockerfiles are just text files, and so your choice of preprocessor or templating language (envsubst, m4, Jinja, ...) will work fine.

You can see this in some of the standard Docker images.  For instance, the [openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) image has Java 7, 8, 10, and 11; with the full JDK, the base runtime, or a stripped-down runtime; for Windows, Debian, or Alpine Linux.  Within the [openjdk GitHub repository](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk) there is a separate Dockerfile for each flavor, but they are all generated by [a hairy bash script](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/master/update.sh).